# How change order of label and input in form ZF1?

Tags: forms, zend-framework, render

How could I get in ZF1 radio form element:

```
<input id="rl-1" name="upload_from" type="radio" value="" checked>
<label for="rl-1">Dodaj z dysku</label>
<input id="rl-1" name="upload_from" type="radio" value="" checked>
<label for="rl-1">Dodaj z dysku</label>
```

when I use:

```
echo $element;
```

Now I have in HTML two times:

```
<label for="type-upload">
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="type-upload" value="upload" checked="checked" />
Dodaj z dysku
</label>
<br />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10433973/3017300

Really is not possible have other structure HTML code without write then step by step? Nothing automating in Zend? Impossible!

Comment: Of course it's possible. Easy and possible, but I think that automating structure by Zend is better to read for developers and easiest in maintenance. Mayby I wrong.